# Fetch only users and not resources

Tags: active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I made a get req to `/v1.0/users` to fetch users but on the response I got resources too.

```
{"id"=>"e7cae970-f906-49f9-b080-8ec0b487c999",
    "businessPhones"=>[],
    "displayName"=>"meeting room 1",
    "givenName"=>nil,
    "jobTitle"=>nil,
    "mail"=>"meetingroom1@test.onmicrosoft.com",
    "mobilePhone"=>nil,
    "officeLocation"=>"location",
    "preferredLanguage"=>nil,
    "surname"=>nil,
    "userPrincipalName"=>"meetingroom1@test.onmicrosoft.com"},
```

How can I only list users and not resources?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a couple of things here, but it depends on how resources are defined in your directory. Often times, directory resources (conference rooms, etc) are missing certain properties that are set for actual users, like `givenName` and `jobTitle`. You can prune resources missing these properties client-side by iterating through and checking what values are present.

For other Graph resources, you can use [OData query options](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc453752356) to filter down to just the subset of resources you want. However, support for filtering on properties of `users` is limited to a few operators like `startsWith`.